# Куда принято сохранять состояния переключателей формы html?

Tags: php, javascript, html, form

Сохранение состояния переключателей формы в переменных сессии это правильно или правильнее писать в базу?
Или если мы закрываем окно и открываем заново, то сессия обновляется?

Т.е. логина на сайт нет, но хотелось бы, чтобы на каждом компьютере сохранялись свои настройки навсегда (ну до переустановки браузера или винды естественно).
В базу писать не хотелось бы в принципе, да и думать нужно к чему привязывать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если необходимо хранить настройки для каждого отдельного браузера, то идеально подойдет сохранение в cookie или localstorage. В базу есть смысл писать только в случае необходимости доступка к одним и тем же настройкам с разных компьютеров, при условии, что пользователь авторизован или есть какая-либо возможность идентифицировать его.

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо! Вопрос остался такой: я в onload присваиваю обработчик change, сразу после присваивания загружаю значение из localstorage, почему change не срабатывает? Если его нужно программно вызвать, то как?

Comment: Сложно сказать без примера кода.

Comment: Как-то так: https://codepen.io/EDIsaev/pen/PRgepN

Comment: Дело в том, что програмное изменение значения (не через ввод с клавиатуры, или кликом по элементу) не вызывает никаких событий. Остается вызывать это событие самому, а вот небольшой пример как это сделать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/813165/179993
Также немного доработал ваш пример https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pLBVVL

Comment: Благодарю, то, что надо!