# Не работает кнопка "показать рядом"

Tags: jquery, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Помогите, пожалуйста, не могу решить вопрос. Сделал кнопку на https://pommeroyal.com/gde-kupit для яндекс-карт с событием

`$(".ryadom").bind("click", function(event){  event.preventDefault(); $('[class*="float-button-icon_icon_geolocation"]').trigger('click');  });`

Все отлично работает, кроме устройств iPhone и iPad. Клики происходят, но trigger('click') не срабатывает, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Тесты показали что работает trigger('click'). Не получается подружиться с картой яндекса в моюильных устройствах iOS

Answer (score 0):

Давно известная проблема. Вместо `trigger('click')` вы можете использовать код, который работает во всех браузерах:

```
let evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("click", true, true); 
document.getElementById(elem_id).dispatchEvent(evt);
```

код взят здесь https://stackoverflow.com/a/15876384/4882290. Там же еще несколько решений данного вопроса

Comment: Написал под jQuery. 
'$('.ryadom').bind('click', function(e) {

  var link = $('[class*="float-button-icon_icon_geolocation"]')[0];
  var linkEvent = null;
  if (document.createEvent) {
    linkEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    linkEvent.initEvent('click', true, true);
    link.dispatchEvent(linkEvent);
  }
  e.preventDefault();  
});'
не помогло

Comment: У MouseEvents скорее всего нет события click. Попробуйте HTMLEvents как в примере

Comment: Пробовал, везде работает, кроме iPad и iPhone

Comment: @MaratShafikov попробуйте другие решения из этого вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/a/15876384/4882290

Comment: К сожалению ни один ответ не помог